# No such file or directory: brownie-config.yaml

Tags: solidity, brownie

I am deploying the deploy.py script

```
# from brownie import FundMe, accounts, config
from brownie import FundMe, accounts
import yaml
import json
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account


# here everything within the env file (for environment variables) is loaded into the python file


def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account}, publish_source=True)
    print("Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}")


def main():
    deploy_fund_me()
```

Here is the brownie-config.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.2

compiler:
  solc: 
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.2'
      
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Here is the error message I am experiencing upon deploying the contract to the rinkeby test network

```
C:\Users\danie\demos\brownie_fund_me>brownie run scripts\deploy.py --network rinkeby 
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieFundMeProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts\deploy.py::main'...
Transaction sent: 0x3cbf0aec47c36be44b5637296ddb83955c016536608d19fd72055ba59df3af05
  Gas price: 1.200000032 gwei   Gas limit: 531117   Nonce: 54
  FundMe.constructor confirmed   Block: 10020242   Gas used: 482834 (90.91%)
  FundMe deployed at: 0xE584303CA3046884145E1d712571969c8334AeA2

  File "C:\Users\danie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 50, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\danie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 103, in run      
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 31, in main
    deploy_fund_me()
  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 26, in deploy_fund_me
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account}, publish_source=True)
  File "C:\Users\danie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 528, in __call__    return tx["from"].deploy(
  File "C:\Users\danie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 557, in deploy   
    contract.publish_source(deployed_contract, silent=silent)
  File "C:\Users\danie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 338, in publish_source
    contract_info = self.get_verification_info()
  File "C:\Users\danie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 295, in get_verification_info
    self._flattener = Flattener(source_fp, self._name, remaps, compiler_settings)
  File "C:\Users\danie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\flattener.py", line 30, in __init__    self.traverse(primary_source_fp)
  File "C:\Users\danie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\flattener.py", line 71, in traverse    self.traverse(import_path)
  File "C:\Users\danie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\flattener.py", line 50, in traverse    source = fp_obj.read_text()
  File "C:\Program, line line, in in
    with self.open(mode='r', encoding=encoding, errors=errors) as f:
  File "C:\Program, line line, in in
    return io.open(self, mode, buffering, encoding, errors, newline,
  File "C:\Program, line line, in in
    return self._accessor.open(self, flags, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\danie\\demos\\brownie_fund_me\\contracts\\brownie-config.yaml'
```

Comment: Can you please upload formatted code instead of screenshots? Also please rename this question to `No such file or directory: brownie-config.yaml`. And please add the script you're running.

Comment: @PatrickCollins Yeah, I changed the post now

Comment: It looks like your `brownie-config.yaml` is in the `contracts` folder. Can you please confirm what folder the `brownie-config.yaml` is in?

Comment: @PatrickCollins, so the brownie-config.yaml file is in the main brownie/_fund_me directory, however, I've noticed that when I don't have the line `publish_source=config["networks"],` in the code it doesn't throw up any errors so I think there could be something wrong with my Infura ethereum client.

Comment: oh definitely try alchemy - and maybe try hard coding the network & publish source.

Answer (score 1):

May not the right answer to your question, but I had nearly a similar Error trying to deploy my brownie contract. In the Smart Contract I wanted to import a smart contract from github using brownie-config.yaml as you did.

This Error pops up: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: `"C:\\Users\\development\\.brownie\\packages\\OpenZeppelin\\openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0\\contracts\\token\\ERC20\\ERC20.sol"`

The Solution:
At the very first time i could easily deploy the contract. Then I wanted to copy the brownie project and run it on another computer. The error came up.

**I need to delete all the files in build > contracts.**
Brownie can now compile the Smart Contracts again and the deployment works fine.